# I have an rectangle and a text object. I would like "text" to follow "rectangle" when i drag him over the canvas

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

```
fabric.Canvas.prototype.getItemsByName = function(name) {
  var objectList = [],
      objects = this.getObjects();

  for (var i = 0, len = this.size(); i < len; i++) {
    if (objects[i].name && objects[i].name === name) {

         if (objects[i].type && objects[i].type === "text") {
      objectList.push(objects[i]);
            }
    }
  }
  return objectList;
};




var moveHandler = function (evt) {
    var movingObject = evt.target;
    //console.log(movingObject.get('left'), movingObject.get('top'));
  var textToMove = canvas.getItemsByName(objectname);
   textToMove.style.left = movingObject.get('left')+'px';// 'px';
   textToMove.style.top = movingObject.get('top')+'px';// 'px'; 
};

canvas.on('object:moving', moveHandler);
```

Code  above finds the text object, but still  is not making text to move behind him. What i am doing wrong?

I am using fabric.js.

I have two objects on canvas. And when i am using event i can see coordinates of  moving objects in console. And also i may get prof of existence of text object which i want to follow the rectangle

```
(var textToMove = canvas.getItemsByName(objectname));
```

But...  I get next

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'left' of undefined next to:
>   textToMove.style.left = movingObject.get('left')+'px';

What is wrong?

```
  var circle1 = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 10,
  fill: 'green',
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  id:objectname+"Circle" ,
  name:objectname      
});


   var text40 = new fabric.Text(objectname, {
   selectable :false,
   left:100,
   top: 80, 
   fontWeight: 'bold',
   fontSize: 12,
   id:objectname+"Text",
   name:objectname
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

If the text is a child of the element that's being moved, just set it's `position` to `relative`. Instead of trying to calculate the pixels to move it to.

Comment: I am creating elements with script code and not in html.

Comment: I need  a little hint.

Comment: And all other properties i need to be independent.

Comment: Did you try putting a try catch around it? It looks like `textToMove` wasn't found and is null.

Answer (score 1):

```
 fabric.Canvas.prototype.getItemByName2 = function(objectname) {
  var object = null,
      objects = this.getObjects();

  for (var i = 0, len = this.size(); i < len; i++) {
    if (objects[i].type && objects[i].type === "text"){
        if (objects[i].name && objects[i].name=== objectname) {
          object = objects[i];
         break;
        }
    } 
  }
  return object;
};

var moveHandler = function (evt) {
    var movingObject = evt.target;
  var leftx = movingObject.get('left');
  var topy = movingObject.get('top');
  canvas.getItemByName2(objectname).set('left',leftx);
  canvas.getItemByName2(objectname).set('top',topy-20);
};

canvas.on('object:moving', moveHandler);
```

As this is working.
Thank you